# Python creating a string using \ and send it in a json request

Tags: python, json, string

I am trying to automate some queries to a API using Python. The problem is that the request needs to be created in a special way, and I just cant make it work. This is the part of the string I am having problems creating.

```
payload = "{\n \"filter\": {\n   \"name\":[\"name1\", \"name2\"]\n }"
```

Where name1 and name2 is variable and is created from a list. The way I tried to do it was just to first create a function to create the

```
[\"name1\", \"name2\"]
```

This is the function

```
def create_string(list_of_names):
#Creates the string of line items we want data from
start = '[\\"%s\\"' % list_of_names[0]    
for i in list_of_names[1 : ]:
    start += ', \\"%s\\"' %(i)

start += "]"

return start

list_of_names = ['name1', 'name2']
```

And then just using the %s part to add it into the string.

```
payload = "{\n \"filter\": {\n   \"name\":%s\n }" % create_string(list_of_names)
```

This doesnt work, and I can think this has something to do with how the \ is used in Python.

The create_string function creates different output depening on if I am printing it or not.

```
a = create_string(list_of_names)
print(a)
```

Creates the string I need to pass in using %s

```
[\"name1\", \"name2\", \"name3\"]
```

And just a outputs

```
'[\\"name1\\", \\"name2\\", \\"name3\\"]'
```

So my problem is then how to pass the print(a) part into the payload string. Does anyone have some sort of solution to this?

Comment: Have you a good reason not to use the json module: `import json; str = json.dumps({'filter': {'name': list_of_names}})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating your payload by hand, first create a python dictionary and use the `json`-module to convert it to a string:

```
payload = {"filter": {"name": list_of_names]}}
payload = json.dumps(payload)
```

or with your more complex dictionary:

```
payload = {
    "filter": {
        "date": "pastThirtyDays",
        "lineitem": {
            "buyType": "RTB",
            "name": list_of_names,
        }
    },
    "metrics": ["cost"],
    "dimensions": ["date", "lineItem"],
}
payload = json.dumps(payload)
```

Comment: your answer might be a little better if you moved the dictionary into a variable. A beginner might not clue into the fact you're creating an actual python dictionary.

Comment: How does that work, does the json.dumps build the query for me then? The original Payload is a bit longer and more complex that this one, and I am not sure how I should add it.                                                            payload = "{\n    \"filter\": {\n        \"date\": \"pastThirtyDays\",\n        \n        \"lineitem\": {\n            \"buyType\": \"RTB\",\n            \"name\": [\"name2\", \"name1\"]\n        }\n     \n        \n    },\n    \"metrics\": [\n        \"cost\"\n        ],\n    \n    \"dimensions\": [\"date\", \"lineItem\"]\n    \n}"

Comment: the json-module converts the python dictionary to a json-string. Instead of your function, it knows all rules, e.g. escaping.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!! It solved my problem, and it helped me understand how the json format works. I have marked the answer as accepted.